# How to map multiple existing term IDs to an entity

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, migrations

I'm trying to map multiple existing terms using their target_id values to an entity (Commerce Product) and I can only get the first value to map.

My yml file looks like this:

```
  'field_prod_category/target_id':
    plugin: explode
    source: tid
    delimiter: ','
```

And, for now, I'm hard coding two existing term ID values in through the source plugin like so:

```
$row->setSourceProperty('tid', '806,635');
```

But no matter what I try only the first term is referenced. And, yes, the term field is set to unlimited.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use plugin [sub_process](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21migrate%21src%21Plugin%21migrate%21process%21SubProcess.php/class/SubProcess). File yml have soure like this:

```
  field_prod_category:
    plugin: sub_process
    source: tids
    process:
      target_id: tid
```

and soure plugin need to prepare:

```
$tids = [
      'tid' => 806,
      'tid' => 635
    ];
$row->setSourceProperty('tids', $tids);
```